# Creating a dictionary with keys being two seperate inputs

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to be able to create a dictionary that combines two inputs as the key and stores the outputs of if and elif functions as the values.

my code so far looks like:

```
    dict = {}
r = int(input("what row:   "))
    c = int(input("what column:   "))
    a = 0.0
    b = 0.0

def weightOn(r,c):
    global a
    global b
    
    if r < 0:
        print('Not valid')
    elif r == 0 and c == 0:
        return a
    elif r > 0 and c == 0:
        a += 200 / (2 ** r)
        return weightOn(r - 1, 0)
    elif r > 0 and c == r:
        a += 200 / (2 ** r)
        return weightOn(r - 1, 0)
weightOn(r,c)

    
if r > c > 0:
    print(b)
else:
    print(a)
```

I would like variables r & c to be the keys, so if I input r as 2 and c as 1 it would save the value as 100. So hopefully my dictionary could look something like: dict = {2.1 :100} and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tuple as key:

```
d = {(r,c): weightOn(r,c)}
```

Depending on the use-case, hierarchical dictionaries might also be useful:

```
d = {r : {c: weightOn(r,c)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you asked, since I don't see you using a dict anywhere in your code snippet, in order to use multiple keys as a dictionary in python, you have to change the data in some way. You can use a tuple, which is essentially creating a list, but instead of using [], you use (). This is the same as a list, but it is immutable. You can also use a list. You can also convert them into a string. Something like:

```py
key = str(r) + str(c)
```

Presumably if you were to do something like:

```py
key = str(r) + " " + str(c)
dict[key] = weightOn(r, c)
```

You would get dict = {"2 1" :100}, so long as your function weightOn works as you intended it to.